# Error Pulling private docker repository from mac Boot2Docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerhub

From my mac, successfully install Boot2Docker and everything seems to work well... 
However when I try to pull a remote private repository using the following command: 
sudo docker pull xxxx/yyyy I get this error message:
FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/images/create?fromImage=xxxx%2Fdev%3Alatest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory

When I try using this command docker pull xxxx/yyyy  I got this error message:
Pulling repository xxxx/yyyy
FATA[0000] Error: image xxxx/yyyy:latest not found

Can anyone already experiment this error message from mac Boot2Docker ? Yes please let me know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting steps

1. Try restarting boot2docker

   `boot2docker restart`
2. ssh into boot2docker `boot2docker ssh` and then see if the docker process is running `ps aux | grep -i '/usr/local/bin/docker -d -D' | grep -v grep`
3. Can you do a `docker pull nginx` from inside boot2docker? This is to test if docker daemon is functional from inside the boot2docker VM
4. Check if the docker daemon unix socket file exists inside the boot2docker VM `ls /var/run/docker.sock`

These steps should help you figure out whats wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I follow all the step you provide and everything looks just fine. Now I do have "FATA[0000] Error: image xxxx/yyyy:latest not found" when I do  sudo docker pull xxxx/yyyy

Comment: Is your private docker repo configured with HTTPS or just HTTP? If it is HTTP only you might need to look at https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#insecure-registries